# I am not able to move the arrow keys or even select the default project while installing the firebase in mac

Tags: firebase, firebase-cli

I was installing firebase for Mac after firebase init command selected firebase and cli features like Databas,Hosting

After pressing enter the terminal asked for project setup but here I am not able to select, enter to not even able to move the arrow keys

I tried closing the terminal and then follow same installation and configuration process but getting stuck at the same step

```
=== Project Setup

First, let's associate this project directory with a Firebase project.
You can create multiple project aliases by running firebase use --add, 
but for now we'll just set up a default project.

? Select a default Firebase project for this directory: (Use arrow keys)
❯ [don't setup a default project] 
  capitalakshay (CapitalAkshay) 
  fir-demo-project (Firebase Demo Project) 
  [create a new project]
```

(Not able to move from here)

Comment: In the future, if you have a problem with the Firebase CLI like this, please contact Firebase support directly so they can collect information about the issue and escalate to engineering.  https://support.google.com/firebase/contact/support

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a similar problem (but in windows) and updating to 7.0.1 I could solve it.

Thank you Doug!!!

Answer (score 3):

**UPDATE**: This problem should be fixed with the [Firebase CLI version 7.0.1](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-tools/releases/tag/v7.0.1).  Install it with `npm install -g firebase-tools@latest`.

For problems where the CLI isn't working properly, please [contact Firebase support](https://support.google.com/firebase/contact/support) so they can collection information and escalate to engineering.  Stack Overflow isn't really the best place to report these sort of issues.

OLD: There is a known problem with an updated dependency of the Firebase CLI that causes it to hang.  There is fix waiting to happen in [this pull request](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-tools/pull/1423), and a new version of the CLI is coming soon.  In the short term, try downgrading your CLI to version 6.3.0 to avoid the problem.

Comment: Just did it and it worked. Thanks for a quick workaround. Installed 7.0.1.

Comment: Thanks Doug! I was using version 7.11.0 but it don´t let me choose the hosting option. I downgraded to 7.0.1 and it worked.

Answer (score 1):

Updated node.js,npm and its working.. Yaayyy!!
just check if you have installed the updated versions

node -v
npm -v

you can update node.js in two ways
1. Download installer from node.js
2.Use command line to update node.js

Use n version manager to update node.js

> npm install -g n
>   npm cache clean -f

{note: terminal may display warning like

npm WARN using --force I sure hope you know what you are doing.}

> sudo n stable
>   {enter your device password}
>
> npm update -g

Now check the updated versions
node -v
npm -v