# Arrow (navigation) dosen't work with ng add @angular/fire in CLI on MAC os. Kinda no response from the terminal

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, angular-cli, angularfire2, firebase-cli

[I am not able to move the arrow keys or even select the default project while installing the firebase in mac](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56686239/i-am-not-able-to-move-the-arrow-keys-or-even-select-the-default-project-while-in) ,this problem seemed to work by updating the NPM version and even updating node.
But now it seems to have reappeared and navigation gets stuck past the point where we choose firebase-project.

Answer (score 0):

Hey I ran into the exact problem.

I dont have the solution to fix the angular cli, however I was able to bypass this using the `firebase init` command.

As the `ng add @angular/fire` has already installed the firebase tools for the project, the `firebase init` command should be able to do the same trick.

Lets hope the Angular team will fix this bug asap.